# Energy Impact: Zero in Xcode 7

Tags: xcode7

I would love to track the energy usage of my iPhone app, unfortunately the Gauge is always saying "Zero". I had this running once, don't know what changed since then. Any ideas what I'm missing?

Comment: isn't xcode 7 at this point of development 'beta' software? Could be possible that it is a bug.

Comment: On 6.3 I also have the memory counter fail to read sometimes. Reboot and restart Xcode helps.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I know the "Energy Impact" graph was working for Xcode 6 and iOS 8 when connected with USB. Now I have upgraded to Xcode 7 and iOS 9 and it no longer works.

Comment: For me it works on Xcode 7 and iOS 9 but only for an iPad 2mini, not for iPhone 6.